# How to block incoming ports using group policy in active directory windows server 2012

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, active-directory-group

We have a domain, and there are some computers in this domain. we applied some many policies like password policy and etc to this domain which makes it easier for us to control the use PC in our organization. Now I wonder if it is possible to stipulate a certain configuration for every PC's firewall in our domain or to force every PC in domain at least block some certain Ports and maybe IPs. Can any one help me? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can create GPOs for the firewall here:

Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Network -> Network Connections -> Windows Firewall

Then apply them to your computer group(s) as desired.